# Helping querying relations in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query in my codebase,

```
$listings = Tag::has('listings')->with(['listings' => function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('moderated', 1)
                ->where('active', 1);

            if($request->query('free') == true) {
                $query->where('cost', '0.00');
            }

            if($request->query('type') != "") {
                $query->with(['types' => function($q) use ($request) {
                    $q->whereIn('id', explode(",", $request->query('type')));
                }]);
            }

            $query->with('primaryImage');
        }])
            ->paginate(3);
```

What I am trying to do is add parts of the query based on what is in the GET request (this bit works), what isnt working is the query on a relation.

Here I am querying Tags that can have many listings, each listing can have many types and I want to only return tags that have listing that match the filter parameters, i.e only show listings that cost "0.00" and then only tags that have listings that match the types in the get request.

So if a user sends `type=1,2,3` in the GET request I want to return tags that have listings where the types relationship contains 1 of those IDs, is this possible?

The types relationship on a listing looks like this,

```
public function types() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Type');
}
```

and the relation from type to listing looks like this,

```
public function listings() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Listing');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using has and with maybe you can use whereHas

```
$listings = Tag::whereHas('listings', function($query){
            $query->where('moderated', 1)
                ->where('active', 1);

            if($request->query('free') == true) {
                $query->where('cost', '0.00');
            }

            if($request->query('type') != "") {
                $query->whereHas('types', function($q) use($request){
                    $q->whereIn('id', explode(",", $request->query('type')));
                });
            }

            $query->with('primaryImage');
        });
```

Comment: I have tried his now no tag gets returned with a listing attribute? When I know for a fact that that 2 of the tags have atleast 1 listing each.

Comment: If you want the return query to include the listing relationship you need to load the relationship using with or directly lazy load in the blade file, the whereHas is only for querying inside the related model.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, "each listing can have many types"

Change this in your **Listing::class**

```
public function types() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Type');
}
```